# Amplify Storage API cannot access protected files by Group Pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

When a user uploads a file as protected, an Admin cannot access it because aws-amplify adds a prefix of user region and user id to the location in storage, but returns only the filename as the key.

Upload as user:

```js
import { Storage } from 'aws-amplify'

const result = Storage.put('file.pdf', file, { level: 'protected', contentType: 'application/pdf' })

// result:
// { key: 'file.pdf' }

// path in aws bucket:
// {user-aws-region}:{user-cognito-identity-id}/file.pdf
```

Why does `Storage.put` not return the full Key to the file?  Because now we need to do a bunch of manual steps to save the `user-aws-region` and `user-cognito-identity-id` somewhere.  Then when accessing the file, we need to check if the signed in user is Admin or owner, and prefix the region & id if not the owner.  When using `Storage.get`

Comment: Why don't you update the bucket policy by adding a role granting approriate access to the Admin.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @SAM.Am, i've updated the question to make it more clear what Im asking about